# can anyone tell me a way to scrape the same data(such as petrol prices form different websites) from different url

Tags: python, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape product data from different websites.
I've tried many things like scraping the websites individually but I want to automate the scraping by only giving URL as a input and getting the data as output

Comment: If you know about web scraping, you can do it by yourself. If you have any issues you can ask here, rather than asking how to do it completely

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - **Please note**, we are not a code-writing service.  
The community is made up of volunteers that give up their free time and share their knowledge.
Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check for URL patterns. Normally in an E-commerce website and similar ones when searching for products the URL ends with a continuous number.
Eg: url&query=&page=1 ends with a continuous number

I usually create an automated script to extract info till the end(using counters as patterns). I show some code snippets I used:

```
def get_page_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "no-result-text--16bWr"})
    if mydivs :
        return None
    return soup

def save_data(vehicle_data):
    with open("data.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        headers = ["Title", "Price", "Brand", "Model", "Edition", "Year", "Condition", "Transmission", "Body", "Fuel", "Capacity", 
            "Mileage","Location", "Description", "Post_URL", "Seller_name", "Seller_type"]
        
        csv_writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        # csv_writer.writeheader()

        for data in vehicle_data:
            csv_writer.writerow(data) 

def export_data(data, site_url=""):

    ad_dict = []

    add_wrapper = data.find('ul', {'class': 'list--3NxGO'})
    children = add_wrapper.findChildren("li" , recursive=False)
    for child in children:
        add_component = child.find('a')
        add_title = add_component.get("title")
        add_link = site_url + add_component.get("href")
        ad_dict.append([add_title,add_link])

    all_vehile_data = extract_multi_pages(ad_dict)
    save_data(all_vehile_data)

def expunge_data():

    baseUrl = input("Enter start url:\n")

    curr_page = 1
    while True:
        data = get_page_data(baseUrl+str(curr_page))
        if data == None:
            break
        else:
            export_data(data)
        print(f"Page {curr_page} done.")
        curr_page += 1 
    

    print("Finished extracting data")
```

Above is a script wrote toextract vehicle data

Alternatively, you could use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) as another option